# How do I Run PowerShell command in windows form application?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, runspace

I am currently trying to implement the below ps command  in my c# forms app.

Im using Quest Powershell cmdlet

```
    Add-PSSnapin -Name Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
    get-qadmemberof -identity 'ssc\rpimentel' | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"} | Add-QADGroupmember -member 'ktest'
```

The powershell command i have works, but i cannot get the below code to work. Command not found Exception is thrown "The term Get-QADMemberOf is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            PSCommand cmd1 = new PSCommand();
            cmd1.AddCommand("Import-Module");
            cmd1.AddParameter("activedirectory");
            cmd1.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin");
            cmd1.AddParameter("Name", "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement");
            cmd1.AddCommand("Get-QADMemberOf");
            cmd1.AddParameter("identity", "rpimentel");
            cmd1.AddCommand("where-object");
            ScriptBlock filter = ScriptBlock.Create("$_.Name -ne 'Domain Users'");
            cmd1.AddParameter("FilterScript", filter);
            cmd1.AddCommand("Add-QADGroupmember");
            cmd1.AddParameter("Member", "ktest");

            ps.Commands = cmd1;
            ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: We'll probably need a bit more information on what you mean by "cannot get it to work in my app" ... Trying running your command in a no-profile powershell to see if it still works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. its a windows form app. i created a method that is executed when i click a button. above is the code i have in that method.

Comment: Yes, so what is the *problem*? How is it not working? What have you tried? Can you get it to do a simpler command in powershell, like `get-childitem`? Edit the question to provide us more details so we can help you.

Comment: The actual powershell command works. Its the C# code that doesnt work. It returns Get-QADMemberOf is not  recognized cmd. I edited my question to show the error through when debugging the code.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about C# coding, but looking at what you've got there I don't see anything that's distinguishing commands that run as separate statements from commmands that are pipelined.  That command construction is missing some bits.

Comment: It looks like there is not enough Invoking going on. It seems like you are running all of it on one line, if it was in a shell. Add two invokes, one after the import module parameter, and another after the add snappin parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment maybe try the following:

```
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

        PSCommand cmd1 = new PSCommand();
        cmd1.AddCommand("Import-Module");
        cmd1.AddParameter("activedirectory");
        ps.Commands = cmd1;
        ps.Invoke();

        cmd1.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin");
        cmd1.AddParameter("Name", "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement");
        ps.Commands = cmd1;
        ps.Invoke();

        cmd1.AddCommand("Get-QADMemberOf");
        cmd1.AddParameter("identity", "rpimentel");
        cmd1.AddCommand("where-object");
        ScriptBlock filter = ScriptBlock.Create("$_.Name -ne 'Domain Users'");
        cmd1.AddParameter("FilterScript", filter);
        cmd1.AddCommand("Add-QADGroupmember");
        cmd1.AddParameter("Member", "ktest");
        ps.Commands = cmd1;
        ps.Invoke();
```